# Converting thousands of PRISM .bil data files to .csv

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, raster

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this has been a problem I've been trying to solve for quite some time.

I have 13877 days worth of climate data from [PRISM](http://www.prism.oregonstate.edu/recent/), daily precipitation data from 01/01/1981 to 12/31/2018. The data I need is "climate data: precipitation," with "temporal period: daily data." From there, data has to be downloaded manually by year as *.bil. The data is floating point, with each .bil file being a raster of dimension 621 x 1405.

I would like to convert and consolidate all these raster files into a single *.csv file using R (or Python). [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222028/merge-multiple-bil-climate-data-into-csv)  seemed close, but I could not get the suggested code to work properly.

With such a large amount of data, I am looking for an efficient solution if possible. My most recent attempt was as follows:

```
#After setting working directory to the folder with all .bil files

library(prism)
library(raster)
library(sp)

type = "ppt"
ls_prism_data(name=TRUE) #lists PRISM files

j = 1
k = 18
final_df = NULL
filepre = paste("PRISM_", type , "_stable_4kmD2_", sep = "")
for (i in 1:771) {
  RS1 <- prism_stack(ls_prism_data()[j:k, 1])
  l = 18
  if (i = 771) {
    l = 17                # 770*18 + 17 = 13877
  }
  j = j + l
  k = k + l
  pr_df <- data.frame(rasterToPoints(RS1))
  long_pr_df <- pr_df %>% gather(Date, type, -x, -y)
  long_pr_df$Dates <- gsub(filepre, "", long_pr_df$Dates)
  long_pr_df$Dates <- gsub("_bil", "", long_pr_df$Dates)
  final_df <- rbind(final_df, long_pr_df)
}
```

My thinking was to convert the data in "batches." Unfortunately, this results in a fatal error that causes R to abort.

Ultimately I would like to get the information to a single file organized by year, by point with column variable denoting precipitation so I can continue this for other climate variables.

I don't need a correction to the above code per se, I'm just looking for a means to an end. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: In order to understand what barriers you are facing I would need to know which bil-formatted files to download to populate a directory and then know what operation is needed. You obviously have some idea what format these files are in, so you need to educate your audience.

Comment: By the way avoid growing objects in a loop such as `rbind` which is memory inefficient.

Comment: @42- Sorry for the incomplete information, I was trying to be concise but maybe too much. The above PRISM hyperlink takes you to the download page. The data I need is "climate data:" "precipitation," with "temporal period:" "daily data." From there, data has to be downloaded manually by year, so it takes going through and choosing a year and downloading all data for that year in .bil. I would like to get the information to a single file organized by year, by point with column variable denoting precipitation so I can continue this for other climate variables.